# Internet Randomly Disconnects: Ethernet Network Adapter Keeps Disconnecting During High Usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, internet, ethernet

My internet keeps randomly disconnecting throughout the day. Its a Dell (Windows 10 - Dell Precision 5770) with Network Adapter: Realtek USB Gbe Family Controller Ethernet. I tried these steps below, no resolution yet:

One thing I noticed, everytime the internet randomly disconnects, I go to Device Manager, and notice the Realtek Network Adapter has totally disappeared from the list (with no option to reenable, even after finding it in Hidden devices). It happens during high internet usage, with many Chrome tabs, and during Zoom calls.

I have to go through these two steps in this order to bring back internet.

1. Restart Computer
2. and then Restart Modem Router. ( I do restart modem by unplugging/plugging back in).

If the ethernet disconnects, Restarting the Modem won't work. Neither will Restarting Computer work. It has two be those two steps above in that specific order. I'm curious if having this resolution path, to understand why ethernet adapter disappears. If you can help target or specify why its occurring?

**Already attempted this:**
and the problem still continues

1. Updated Dell Drivers
2. Windows Update
3. Network Adapter Troubleshooter
   [image]
4. (a) Network Reset and (b) tried manually uninstalling/reinstalling network drivers separately
   [image]
5. Tried manually downloading the software drivers at Realtek website https://www.realtek.com/en/downloads
6. Replace cable just in case, but the other computer in home does not have internet randomly disconnect
7. Tried:

```
netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
netsh winsock reset and press Enter
netsh int ip reset and press Enter
ipconfig /release and press Enter
ipconfig /renew and press Enter
ipconfig /flushdns and press Enter
```

8. Disable these three in Device Manager:
   (a) Energy Efficient Internet
   (b) Green Ethernet
   (c) Wake on Magic Packet
9. In Device Manager, changed Power Management settings.

[image]

I use the modem with another computer, and no issues whatsoever, until I got a new computer.

Comment: This question appears closely related to this;   https://superuser.com/questions/1775806/windows-ethernet-randomly-disconnects-power-management-options-for-realtek

Comment: hi @Ramhound i use the modem with another computer, and no issues whatsover, until I got a new computer

Comment: hi @harrymc updated details in question

Comment: (My comment was deleted somehow and I don't know what it was.) I would suggest to try an external USB network adapter, to see if the problem is with your new computer's adapter.

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you may find a new [Realtek driver](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software) that you could try.

Comment: Have you looked through the windows event viewer system logs? Might be something useful in there.

Comment: 1) Try to run Dell Command Update and use all the updates you get THERE. Other softwares sometime suggest different drivers. 2) If this only happens during high-usage, it might be a problem with the hardware itself. Does the computer still under warranty? If so, I'd suggest you contact Dell support.

Comment: ummm I missed the part where you need to restart the modem. Are you sure that's part of the problem? Have you tried to connect the RJ45 cable into another port on the modem? What is the make of your modem? Does the rest of the devices access the internet when the problem occurs?

Comment: yeah, I have restarted modem 100 times @Netan

Comment: I asked, like, 5 things. Y U answer only about one? Also, What happens when you restart the computer without restarting the router. How does that looks like?? "NOT WORKING" isn't enugh. Is the driver connected and working? Are there blinking LEDs on the RJ45 connector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I go to Device Manager, and notice the Realtek Network Adapter has totally disappeared from the list (with no option to reenable, even after finding it in Hidden devices)

Hidden devices are devices that are configured but currently not available to the system (unplugged, errors).

- *The state of the device in failing mode can be seen in the details of the device in the device manager.*
- *As an error is to be suspected, the details in the system event log of Windows would be of interest.*
  => *Please integrate a log-excerpt to the question.*

> I have to go through these two steps in this order to bring back internet.
>
> 1. Restart Computer
> 2. and then Restart Modem Router. ( I do restart modem by unplugging/plugging back in).
>
> If the ethernet disconnects, Restarting the Modem won't work. Neither will Restarting Computer work. It has two be those two steps above in that specific order.

As you have to restart both, computer and router a driver error is not the top hit in probability. Obviously you trigger a problem at the hardware level (ethernet or electric).

- You already changed the wires and drivers. — Good idea.
  **EDIT:** Which driver did you install? And where did you get it from?
  => I would expect  Version `1153.9.823.2022, A28` / 19 Oct 2022 from
  [Dell Driver Support](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=6621f&oscode=w2021&productcode=precision-17-5770-laptop)
- Please update the BIOS also: You're lucky, there is a brand new one:
  https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/precision-17-5770-laptop/drivers
  [image]

Do not forget to reset the BIOS settings.

If the error persists:

- The RJ45 sockets often have a multi-colored LED to indicate their state (router and PC).
  Please compare the state at normal/erratic behavior.
- Does the other computer (connected to the same router) have flawless internet connection when the Dell is in error mode?
  If TRUE: Does this change if you only disconnect the RJ45 plug of the Dell?
- In error mode:

  1. Disconnect RJ45 and wait a few minutes. – Does the device unhide in the device manager?
  2. If 1. is TRUE: Does Internet come back when you change the RJ45 slot instead of rebooting the router?
  3. If 2. is FALSE: Leave the plug in the changed RJ45 slot. and reboot the computer. — Does the Internet come back now?

> the other computer in home does not have internet randomly disconnect

By this you have the proof, the router itself is working. But you do not have the proof, the RJ45 socket at the router is flawless.

=> Please exchange the plugs between your working computer and the computer with the problems. — Now you can check:

1. The error persists *(not the RJ45)*
2. The error moves to the other computer *(RJ45 at router defect)*
3. The error disappears *(multiple reasons)*

Edit: Meanwhile you write about a *"modem router"*.

- Does this device have multiple RJ45 slots? — Perhaps you publish the device name and model number.
- Where do you have to enter the credentials to get connected to the internet?
- Is a special software required (i.e. by the internet provider) to get connected?

I'll update, when your answers appear.

Comment: thanks, will test next time, do you want me to not only get new rj45 plugs, but new power wires plugs in general?

Comment: The router has multiple RJ45 sockets (RJ45 jacks). It is possible that one or more of them are defective. So testing against a known good one is helpful to narrow down the error. The theme block "power supply" would be the next test if the these test fail and give a hint. But as you state, the other PC works well at same conditions, the RJ45 jack has more probability, so we test the data wiring first. — And *PLEASE*:  Do **not** change the other setup (new power supplies, etc.) as multiple changes in one test cycle will will render the test results senseless creating random results.

Comment: @mattsmith5 To be able to continue, I would (1) appreciate to see the answers to my questions. Especially the windows system log can provide valuable hints.

Comment: sent it you, Im not having any issues anymore, but thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today after updating my dell via support assist. no more dns resolution with the new Realtek GBE usb driver.
In device manager i klick get previous driver version (which was 10.24.326.2018) and immediatly dns was available again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Have you tried to update again, then set the DNS manually to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8? Have you tried to restart the computer after the update?

Answer (score 0):

its probably a incompatibility between the new driver and your old router/modem so if you still want to force use it you will have to downgrade the realtek driver version or you will have to get a new router

also do check your bios/os power management aswell cause there used to be a bug where due to a power saving feature the ethernet would unset (driver freezes) till the next boot even after the boot we would have to disconnect the eth. and wait for 10s and then reconnect it again