# Intermittent Internet connection loss

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

Randomly from random device cannot connect via tcp/udp to any external address. Ping works, dns works, all internal access works.

I have a very strange issue with my home networks internet access and honestly I am running out of ideas. In my home network, I have an internet router, some PowerLine adapters to connect different floors (some also act as access points) and a plug-and-play desktop switch on my office table connecting one of the PowerLine adapters with the router. Randomly a device (iOS, MacOS, Windows, Sonos, TV, Raspi, you name it) around the house suddenly will be unable to connect to any external network address, regardless if it's connected via WiFi (either to one of the PowerLine adapter SSIDs or directly to the routers Wifi SSID), via cable directly to the desktop switch or via ethernet cable to any of the PowerLine adapters. Rebooting the device, disconnecting/reconnecting the ethernet cable, turning wireless on/off, release the IP assigned via DHCP, clearing the DNS cache, changing the MAC address, setting an IP manually, connecting to LAN instead of WiFi won't fix it.

Now the funny thing: During the whole time of the problem the affected device is able to successfully use DNS lookup to resolve any external address to an IP AND ping it without issues (DNS is the router IP). Yet when running a portscan on any of the resolved IPs (for ex. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) there are always 0 open ports and all other ways of trying to connect instead of ping will fail. All the time during the error the device is still able to access any internal hosts INCLUDING the default gateway - which is the router without any issues and vice versa.

If I pull and immediately reconnect the network cable between router and desktop switch it instantly starts working again on the affected device. But why? From the error it's like there would be a sudden firewall blocking all outbound tcp/upd traffic of the device. I cannot be an ARP or routing issue since I am always able to ping the destination or any other host.

I have already bought a completly new desktop switch (with some small management features) and replaced the router including switching from DSL to 5G mobile network as means of internet access, yet the issue still remains and affects like explained every device in my home network randomly.
(Yes I have also replaced cables, but if you read my description other devices will work yet when I pull the cable that a) connects all devices to the upstream router it will start working on the one device that fails, it also fixes the issue if the device doesn't work although it's directly on the SSID of the upstream router - which makes no sense)

The last thing I did was disable ARP proxy on the router (why was this enabled by default?) but I didn't see how this could cause the issue and so the issue re-appeared only minutes afterwards on another phone.

I am totally running out of ideas any thoughts would be appreciated.

Some other infos.
I am using DHCP. DHCP server is the router.
I am not using a mesh network.
TP-Link is the vendor of PowerLine and Desktop Switch (old desktop switch was also TP-Link but not configurable).
ZTE is the vendor of the 5G wireless router (old one was Huawei DSL modem - same issue).

Thanks

Comment: Please give us a TL;DR summary at the top.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=Intermittent+Internet Have you tried disconnecting all the devices one by one and check if the problem keeps occuring, if so, have you asked the ISP to change router? Have you set the DNS to 8.8.8.8? https://www.tp-link.com/nl/support/faq/3010/

Comment: Have you tried not using the PowerLine adapters?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1775819/internet-randomly-disconnects-ethernet-network-adapter-keeps-disconnecting-duri

Comment: When there is a problem with one of the devices, I have already tried to disconnect all PowerLine adapters around the house (so they are completely powered off). I didn't fix the issue for the one device, only pulling and plugging the cable between router and the switch does even if the device is connected to the SSID of the router directly.

Comment: I will try to set the DNS to 8.8.8.8, but as explained DNS is working fine still if one device has an issue (and that includes of course clearing the DNS cache), it returns correct IPs, but regardless of DNS or IP a portscan will always yield zero open ports only ping continues to work.